# Why parse_qsl does not work for empty value?

Tags: python-3.x, urllib

I don't quite understand why no results are returned when the value is empty. Is there a way to get the key value pair when the value is empty? Thanks.

```
>>> urllib.parse.parse_qsl('a=b')
[('a', 'b')]
>>> urllib.parse.parse_qsl('a=')
[]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `keep_blank_values` parameter. By the way, what version of python are you using. This is what I get when I use the keep_blank_values. By default it is set to `False`. And I use python version `3.8.2`

```py
Python 3.8.2 (tags/v3.8.2:7b3ab59, Feb 25 2020, 23:03:10) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from urllib.parse import parse_qsl
>>> parse_qsl('a=b')
[('a', 'b')]
>>> parse_qsl('a=')
[]
>>> parse_qsl('a=', keep_blank_values=True)
[('a', '')]
>>>
```